# how to track object in scene from far to near in opencv

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I need to track the cars on the road, it is possible to monitor the object change with GMM, however the cars on the road change its size from far to near, what algorithm is suggested to track the object from far to near or near to far?

Comment: You can try block matching, 8X8 or 4X4 blocks and match using SAD. It will tell you the change in size and translation also. If the object is large and not very fast, you can handle it's rotation also.
Write back if you need further details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gaussian Mixture Models (GMM) isn't a bad choice for modelling cars as objects but I am not sure how you would model background with it since it can be much more heterogeneous and require a large mixture. Learning GMM with EM (Expectation Maximization) can be processing intensive. So my advice is to start using simple histograms that will model the object as a collection of bins with counts instead of collection of Gaussian distributions. Below I describe two such methods implemented in OpenCV.

The simplest way to start tracking using openCV is by using a [meanshift](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=meanshift#cv.MeanShift) function. A related method, [Camshift](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=camshift#cv.CamShift) is a modified version of meanshift that also corrects the size and orientation of initial bounding box when the object change its size or orientation. You can find a corresponding demo in camshiftdemo.c of openCV package.

The input to both meanshift and camshift is a probability map where each pixel indicates (approximately) what is the chance that it belongs to the object (and possibly background). One way to create such a map is to calculate the histogram of the object you want to track and then backproject it into the image, so if, for example, your histogram has only two bins with count 90 for I=255 and count 10 for I=100 each pixel with intensity 255 gets 90% probability and each pixel with intensity 100 gets 10% (see more detailed explanation about histogram [backprojection](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html?highlight=backp#cv.CalcBackProject)).

Note that these methods are based on histograms of some features such as intensity, color, or virtually anything else. You can try to add more feature histograms and also correct your probability map relating your object histogram to the histogram of the background. Finally you can update your histograms at each frame to compensate for object and background changes.

Now, in short, how it works. The meanshift, as the name suggests, moves your initial window according to the position of the probability mean (calculated within this window) and the mean is typically biased (shifted) away from the window center and towards the highest probability cluster (hopefully your object). This process repeats iteratively until convergence.

Of course, if your initial guess is too far away from the real probability maximum the window can get stuck in the local maximum that has nothing to do with your object. Thus a high frame rate is important since it would guarantee that the object doesn't move much between frames and you can use a previous location as a reasonable guess for a window position initialization.

Comment: Hi, Vlad, I admit GMM to model the scene is bit heavy, I would like to try camshift. I have also seen the use of kalman filter for tracking objects, how it related to tracking, what is the advantage of using kalman ?

Comment: In short, a Kalman filter will analyse a tracking(motion) history to improve your estimate. For example if the object moves to the right you can place an initial window slightly to the right of the previous position. This will compliment rather than change your solution. Do this at the end after you polish your camshift.

Comment: Hi, Vlad, in order to use the meanshift method for the car tracking, first of all I need to get the histogram of the car. One more question is when there is a car coming from far to near, how does the application first detect new car, select this car's histogram,

Comment: Background subtraction can help you to break a scene on movable segments.